# FromBody is null next migrating to ASP .Net Core MVC 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP .Net Core MVC 2.0 application.

Everything works fine.

I have migrated to 3.1 Framework. I have now a problem with this code:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<JsonResult> my_auth([FromBody] JObject data)
{
    String _login = (String) data["login"];
    String _mot_de_passe = (String) data["password"];
    ...
}
```

The data object is null and i do not know why.

I have checked client and post body is sent...

Any idea ?

Thanks

*** EDIT ***

Here is the http query:

```
POST /my_auth HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 39
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/xxxxxx Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7

{"login":"test","password":"1234"}
```

Comment: Might be silly question, but you are hitting your actino right? its just that `data` is null? Can you also show the data you are sending in the request

Comment: see my edit. I have paste the full http request

Comment: is `{"login":"test","password":"1234"}` your request payload? it doesn't look like it, show the code sending the request or show the actual payload (you can redact your actual details). Also, are you hitting the action if you debug? You have given too little information to help

Comment: Yes it is the POST payload data. I have capture this request with a sniffer. What do you need else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the work to improve the ASP.NET Core shared framework, `Newtonsoft.Json` has been removed from the ASP.NET Core shared framework for asp.net core 3.x.

Follow the steps:

- Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package on nuget.

  ```
  Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
  ```
- Update `Startup.ConfigureServices` to call `AddNewtonsoftJson`.

  ```
  services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
  ```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-newtonsoftjson-in-an-aspnet-core-30-mvc-project

Answer (score 0):

Try using "JsonElement" instead of "JObject" like this:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> my_auth([FromBody]JsonElement data)
{
    var _login = data.GetProperty("login").GetString();
    var _mot_de_passe = data.GetProperty("password").GetString();
    //...
}
```

You should use **System.Text.Json** namespace.

Comment: I have this error: "System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Alternatively, give the 'data' parameter a non-null default value."

Comment: How do you send a post request to the app?