# implement CRUD functionality with static data using JSON in asp.net core api project

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi

How to do Crud operation on a locally stored json file? For example, I have  id, name and roll number. I want to do get, post, put and delete in it using asp.net core Web API. But I should not use database to store the data instead I need to store the data  in controller using method and use it to do the http operations. Can any one please help me with some step or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Get the json file:

```
var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\Repos\\test.json");
```

[image]

2.Delete the json file:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Repos\test.json"))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Repos\test.json");
}
```

3.Put the json file:

```
var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\Repos\\test.json");   
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject>(data);

jsonObj["id"] = 4;

string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\Repos\\test.json", output);
```

[image]

4.Add new column to the json file:

```
var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\Repos\\test.json");

var jObj = JObject.Parse(data);
jObj["NewField"] = "value";
var newjson = jObj.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\Repos\\test.json", newjson);
```

[image]

**Note:**

If you use **beyond ASP.NET Core 3.x**, you need add Newtonsoft support.

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61400253/11398810

Comment: Hii @rena thanks...this answer has resolved my problem tysm.